# creating interface for adding n number of products to a category using umbraco

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I know this question has been asked many times i went through all of them but couldn't find the right solution hence writing my problem here may be again...

I want to create CMS for category-Products solution..i think the name itself is  quite explanatory..

Every category can have n number of products  in to it. 
but i couldnt get how can i do this via umbraco.
i know, i can access child not via inline razor macro but how to access child node contents ...or may be some other right way!!

Please dont give me links to Run away modules..i have already visited them ...and could understand very little...

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Sangeeta, I would suggest that you spend the time to read documentation, watch training videos and get to know Umbraco better in general. That way you can ask more specific answers that make more sense and we can provide better answers. You also may want to spend a little more time on your punctuation and grammar so as to be as clear and succinct as possible.

Comment: Umbraco has a great community and we are all too happy to help. I've answered the part of your question below, it was unclear to me what you were asking exactly as far as razor macros are concerned.

Comment: oops!! sorry for that. i will try to improve. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create (if you haven't already) two different [document types](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/working-with-document-types); one called Category, the other called Product. (You'll also want to add the appropriate properties.) In the Structure tab of Category, be sure to allow Product (and don't forget to allow Category under whatever type it will live). From here, you should be able to create Category nodes, and then beneath each of them, Product nodes.

Comment: i solved that using inline razor macro.. I was trying to access contents of child products of any category.